# Duplicate Content-Type headers in Nginx for CSV files

Tags: nginx

I have some `.csv` files that I'm serving via Nginx straight from the filesystem.
It currently looks like this::

```
location ~ /static/csv_exports/ {
        add_header Content-Type text/csv;
}
```

For some reason I had to do that because otherwise it would be served as `text/plain`. Here's what I get when I do a curl on it:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost/static/csv_exports/20110322_172651.csv >> /dev/null
...
 < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 < Server: nginx/0.7.67
 < Date: Tue, 22 Mar 2011 17:32:07 GMT
 < Content-Type: text/plain
 < Content-Length: 356623
 < Last-Modified: Tue, 22 Mar 2011 17:26:52 GMT
 < Connection: keep-alive
 < Cache-Control: public
 < Content-Type: text/csv
 < Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

See! It's got two "Content-Type" headers. Opening it in the browser automatically opens Open Office and it works just fine but I suspect I haven't done it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
location ~ /static/csv_exports/ {
-    add_header Content-Type text/csv;
+    types {text/csv csv;}
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about the `types` directive thing.

Comment: Worked for me too, when making nginx return custom string it adds text/plain content type.