# Why is Chrome not displaying Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 returned from nginx

Tags: google-chrome, http, nginx, content-type

I want to set the Content-Type header in response returned from Nginx to `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8` instead of the default `Content-Type: text/html`. So after applying the method posted in [Duplicate Content-Type headers problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395475/duplicate-content-type-headers-in-nginx-for-csv-files),
Chrome doesn't display the Content-Type header. However, curl shows that the content type header returned from Nginx is set correctly. Anybody know why? Thanks in advance!

My Nginx configuration is as follow.

```
location /rogers/ {
    types   {"text/html;charset=utf-8" html;}
    alias   /opt/nginx/html/;
    index   test.html;
}
```

Curl result is as follow.

[image]

Chrome result is as follow.

[image]

Comment: Clear Chrome's cache and retry.

Comment: Thanks, it works.